# why linker to do "targeting of absolute jumps, loads and stores."

Tags: c++, linker

from [Wikipedia - linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing))

> The linker also takes care of arranging the objects in a program's address space. This may involve relocating code that assumes a specific base address to another base. Since a compiler seldom knows where an object will reside, it often assumes a fixed base location (for example, zero). Relocating machine code may involve re-targeting of absolute jumps, loads and stores.

What is the purpose of "targeting of absolute jumps, loads and stores." ?

Comment: Because the addresses of the objects have changed, for the reasons that were just immediately stated.

Answer (score 0):

A compiler seldom knows where an object will reside, so it often assumes a fixed base location (for example, zero). Relocating machine code may involve re-targeting of absolute jumps, loads and stores. The linker does this.

Notice that I simply rearranged some words in your own quote.